# Find the largest substring which contains equal number of 0s and 1s in a binary string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Recently in an interview I was asked to write a program to find the largest sub string which contains equal number of `0`s and `1`s in a binary string.

**For example:**

If the given string is `1010111` then the output will be `1010` as it contains 2 `0`s and 2 `1`s.

I tried a lot but can't come up with anyway to build an algorithm for this thing.

Can someone give me head start on how to proceed or what data structure to use for this problem ?

Comment: would it help if you consider 0 values as -1? reducing the problem to finding the maximum length of the array with a sum of 0?

Comment: Wouldn't `0101` (starting by the 1st 0)also work? Or is it the **first** to be found?

Comment: @SamerTufail I think this problem can be replaced considering any 2 numbers or even characters, so I think finding a sum of 0 is not correct

Comment: @M.K since main point is to find the longest, so I think `0101` can be considered too

Comment: @VivekMishra if its any two numbers or any two characters you can map it to -1 and 1 as well. How can you disprove that finding a sum of 0 is not correct?

Comment: @SamerTufail sorry didn't understood the full context. If you are talking about mapping context then it can work

Comment: what should be o/p for : 00001111?

Comment: @SJC in this case whole string will be the output

Comment: This is a common example of context free languages. With one extra output tape, you can do it in $O(n)$. Build a stack, when you see $1$ or $0$(one of them , keep pushing that symbol on the stack, when you see opposite of that then keep removing the symbol). Largest string will be initial stack size(when you finished pushing 1st symbol ) minus the stack size at the end.

Comment: Searching the internet would have helped you find some algorithms and implementations. I found one here for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-subarray-with-equal-number-of-0s-and-1s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution isn't the best one in terms of optimisation, but in the hurry and the stress of an interview, this one can be quickly thought, drawn and explained.

I would nest 2 loops.

1 starting from 0 to len - 2 (incrementing) (the minimal length should be 2)

1 starting from len to previous loop value + 2 (decrementing) (the minimal length should be 2)

Get the substring of the corresponding iterators of the loops

Count if the characters are equal.

then, if true, compare against stored result length, if the length is greater, overwrite the result.

Using `0100` as example, that will test against those values :

```
// result = ''
0100 //not balanced
010  //not balanced
01   //balanced AND length is greated than result's one. result = '01'
 100 //not balanced
 10  //balanced BUT length is not greated than result's one
  00 //not balanced
```

JavaScript example (I tweaked it a bit to optimise the number of iterations, but the approach is the same) :

```js
var iterations = 0;

function IsBalanced(input, char1, char2)
{
    if (input.length % 2 != 0) // odd length can't be balanced
    {
      ++iterations;
      return (false);
    }
    let char1count = 0;
    let char2count = 0;
    let len = input.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        ++iterations;
        if (input[i] == char1)
            ++char1count;
        else
            ++char2count;
    }
    return (char1count == char2count);
}

function findLargest(input, char1, char2)
{
    let len = input.length;
    let result = '';
    for (let k = 0; k < len - 1; ++k)
    {
        //        This is a tweak to reduce the number of iterations
        //  To avoid testing a substring smaller than the current result
        //                           |
        //                           |
        //                v----------------------v
        for (let l = len; l - k > result.length && l > k + 1; --l)
        {
            tempResult = input.substring(k, l);
            if (IsBalanced(tempResult, char1, char2) && tempResult.length > result.length)
                result = tempResult;
        }
    }
    return (result);
}

console.log("Input : 1010111 - result : " + findLargest("1010111", "1", "0") + " original size : " + "1010111".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
iterations = 0;
console.log("Input : ababaaa - result : " + findLargest("ababaaa", "a", "b") + " original size : " + "ababaaa".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
iterations = 0;
console.log("Input : 00100100 - result : " + findLargest("00100100", "1", "0") + " original size : " + "00100100".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
iterations = 0;
console.log("Input : 1111100000 - result : " + findLargest("1111100000", "1", "0") + " original size : " + "1111100000".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
iterations = 0;
console.log("Input : 0001111111111010001111100000000001111111111 - result : " + findLargest("0001111111111010001111100000000001111111111", "1", "0") + " original size : " + "0001111111111010001111100000000001111111111".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
iterations = 0;
console.log("Input : 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 - result : " + findLargest("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", "1", "0") + " original size : " + "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001".length + " - iterations : " + iterations);
```

Answer (score 10):

The following will work in *O(n)* time and space, *n* being the number of characters in the string.

- keep track of the current `balance` (or imbalance) of `1` and `0` you've seen in the `string`, and the `first` time the string had the same balance (an array or map with at most `n` entries)
- iterate the `string`, and for each character...

  - update the `balance`, counting `"1"` as `1` and `"0"` as `-1` or vice versa
  - check when, if at all, you encountered the same `balance` before
  - if the difference is greater than the current `best`, remember the new longest substring
  - if you haven't encountered that balance yet, remember it's current `first` position

Example code in Python:

```py
string = "1010111000"
first = {0: 0}  # map or array; 0th element is 0
balance = 0     # initially, 1 and 0 are balanced
best = ""       # best substring found
for i, c in enumerate(string):             # (i, c) = (index, character)
    balance += 1 if c == "1" else -1       # update balance
    if balance not in first:               # first time we see this balance?
        first[balance] = i+1               # add next(!) position to map/array
    elif i - first[balance] > len(best):   # otherwise, if new longest substring
        best = string[first[balance]:i+1]  # update best with slice of string
    print(i, c, balance, best, first)      # debugging/demo output
```

Output:

```py
0 1 1  {0: 0, 1: 1}
1 0 0 10 {0: 0, 1: 1}
2 1 1 10 {0: 0, 1: 1}
3 0 0 1010 {0: 0, 1: 1}
4 1 1 1010 {0: 0, 1: 1}
5 1 2 1010 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 6}
6 1 3 1010 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7}
7 0 2 1010 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7}
8 0 1 01011100 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7}
9 0 0 1010111000 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7}
```

Comment: By imbalance do you mean keeping count of 0 and 1 in an array/dictionary ? Or difference between count

Comment: `balance += 1 if c == "1" else -1` pretty much what I had stated in the first comment, the problem has now been reduced to finding the maximum subarray with `sum = 0`

Comment: @SamerTufail Yes, I guess we had the same idea here. Wasn't entirely clear from your comment, in particular that you can't just regard all the positions where `sum=0` but all where it's the same as any previous value.

Comment: `you can't just regard all the positions where sum=0` - Why not? if it is `0` then that means the `sum` value is `sum-1` where sum starts at 0 and all positions with `sum = 0` are potential answers.

Comment: @SamerTufail Maybe that was not quite clear. I meant that you can not just regard the places where (in my code) the "balance" is zero, as those would just be the substrings starting at the first index. You also need a list/map of first positions of other balances or sums, as you have in your algorithm, too.

Comment: Ah, okay sorry yes, I misunderstood. :)

Comment: @tobias_k I am not familiar with python, so I want to ask does `c` stands for character of the string ? And `first` is an array ?

Comment: @VivekMishra Exactly, `i` is the current position and `c` the character. `first` is a map/dictionary/associative array, but you can also use a regular array or list of size `n`, with all elements initialized as e.g. `-1` except the 0th which has to be `0`.

Comment: Also can you explain what this line is doing ? `best = string[first[balance]:i+1]`.

Comment: @VivekMishra That gets the substring from the position stored in the `first` map/array up to and including the current posiiton.I added comments to each line. Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach it like this

- Initialise a variable integer sum and maxlength = minimum
- Define a hashmap with with sum as key and index as value
- For each value in the given string

  - sum += arr[i] == 0 ? then add -1 otherwise add a 1
  - if the sum is 0 maxlength = maxlength or index + 1 since this is a potential answer
  - else if dictionary contains that sum value, maxlength = maxlength or
    (i -index hash[sum]) the sum value found earlier contributing to the result.
  - update the hashmap if the value of sum is not in the hash map with
    index
  - return the maximumlength.

Here is an example for what I mentioned above, in code : [working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f4851485358898f) you can try changing the test case to see how this would work for various test cases, try printing the hash map as well and trace it by hand to gain a deeper understanding.